# encrypted connection string does not work across servers

Tags: asp.net, .net, encryption, connection-string

I have a .net application compiled and I am moving it from one server to the other server. The connection string is compiled. And this application connects and works fine from server A.
When I move the compiled application into server B which has the same database backend the application is not connecting.

I see that the encrypted connection string is not working. Is there a way to fix this? The backend server connectivity is perfectly fine and ports are open. still the connection string is not working. Any clue on how this can be fixed?

Comment: Actually you provided too little information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your connection string is encrypted with a certificate thumbprint installed on machine A, which is why it works fine there. However, When you moved your application to machine B, you might have missed installing the certificate.

Ensure that, if the encryption of the connection string is based on a certificate thumbprint, the certificate is also installed on the target machine.

Comment: Actually - I'd be curious how you know that as the question doesn't provide any useful information (any specific product or assignment?)

Comment: We had a similar setup in one of our previous projects, so just thought it could be one potential issue.

Comment: @RajuDasupally Thanks a lot. that was the actual issue and machine key was holding us from migrating this application. Thanks!

Comment: @Rick, glad it helped you!